# Why does my image disappear when I surround it with an <a> tag on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Initially, this code:

```
<%= image_tag(thumbnail(drawing.image_url), class: "drawing")%>
```

which resulted in:

```
<img class="drawing" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/brandonliu/image/upload/t_thumb_large/v1430498900/00001.jpg" alt="00001">
```

worked just fine, but as soon as I switched it to a link_to:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(thumbnail(drawing.image_url), class: "drawing"), drawing %>
```

the image stopped displaying. The image in fact disappears anytime I surround it with a hyperlink tag, does anyone know why?

EDIT: I don't think the problem is with the rails syntax, because simply doing

```
<a><%= image_tag(thumbnail(drawing.image_url), class: "drawing")%></a>
```

still does not allow the image to display

Answer (score 2):

Try pass a block with `image_tag` to the [`link_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) helper:

```
<%= link_to some_path_here do %>
  <%= image_tag(thumbnail(drawing.image_url), class: "drawing") %>
<% end %>
```

From documentation:

> You can use a block as well if your link target is hard to fit into
>   the name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`image_tag` renders the string

```
<img src="...">
```

which is the image tag.  To make a link, you need the path to the image, not a rendering of a tag.

Try this

```
<%= link_to image_path(thumbnail(drawing.image_url)) %>
```